# Why the output is different in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have tow var looks like some string. but the `output` show unicode, and `output1` show right charactor. All typeof is string.

```
        const output = stdout.match(/"dst":"(.*)"/)[1];
        log('xxx=>', output, typeof output);    // xxx=>, \u6536\u5230, string
        const output1 = '\u6536\u5230';
        log('xxx=>', output1, typeof output1); // xxx=>, 收到, string
```

Answer (score 2):

`\` characters have special meaning (they are escape sequences) in string literals in JS source code.

They don't have special meaning in external input.

Comment: I guess the question becomes “how do you convert the string to JS escape sequences”?